# Not able to print the data with getData() Function

Tags: magento-1.9, error, collection

I am trying to join two tables with join operation

```
$layoutscoll = Mage::getModel('pdp/pdplayouts')->getCollection();
$query = $layoutscoll->getSelect()
    ->join(array('layoutsides'=>'mst_pdp_multisides'), 'main_table.id= layoutsides.id', array());
echo $query;
print_r($query->getData());
```

When I print this `$query` using `echo` it shows an "SQL query" it's works on PhpMyadmin SQL queries. But I want print this in blocks or templates by using `getData()` it shows error. I think that `getData()` function not works here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$query` in your case is an instance of `Zend_Db_Select` that does not have the method `getData`.
I assume you want to print the results of the query.
You can do that with `print_r($layoutscoll->getIterator())`.
That might not work either. You may get a long object printed. if it does not work try with

```
foreach ($layoutscoll as $item) {
    print_r($item->getData());
}
```

Comment: I got Same Issue   exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`basemage_mage`.`catalog_product_super_link`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_SPR_LNK_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE)' in /chroot/home/basemage/basemage.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:

Comment: I'm sure tthat the error has nothing to do with the code you posted. There is no insert or update in the code. Just selects. Selects should not trigger that error.